# Trying to get a symbol

Tags: math-mode

How can I get this:

[image]

MWE:

```
$i^{'}$
```

Comment: `$i'$` or `$i^\prime$` should do.

Comment: I keep seeing `x^{'}` in Math.SE. I'm not sure where this originated from, but it's *very* wrong. Either `x^{\prime}` or `x'`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=code%3A%22%5E%27%22